# DDD - How does the domain receive client data

Tags: c#, design-patterns, domain-driven-design

I'm planning to refactor a legacy .NET project that I'm maintaining, there are mainly 4 projects involved:

- `My.Company.Web` - The presentation layer. ASP.NET MVC.
- `My.Company.Service` - The service layer, defines service interfaces and contains command handlers. Invoked by the web layer.
- `My.Company.DTO` - The assembly that contains DTO classes for data transfer between the domain and web layers.
- `My.Company.Domain` - The domain layer.
- `My.Company.Data` - The persistence layer.

When user submits a form to update a person's details, the process looks somewhat like this:

1. Using the submitted data, controller constructs a `PersonDetailsDTO` which consists of multiple simple fields to hold `FirstName`, `LastName`, `Age` and etc, and a complex type object called `AddressDTO` that holds address details: `var dto = new PersonDetails(...);`
2. Controller calls the service layer with the DTO:

   ```
   _personService.UpdateDetails(dto);
   ```
3. In the service:

   ```
   public void UpdatePerson(PersonDetailsDTO dto)
   {
       var person = _personRepository.GetById(dto.PersonId);
       person.Update(dto);
       _personRepository.Update(person);
   }
   ```
4. In the Person domain:

   ```
   public class Person : AggregateRoot
   {
       private string FirstName;
       .... // other fields
       private Address Address;

       public void Update(PersonDetailsDTO dto)
       {
           FirstName = dto.FirstName;
           .... // other fields
           Address.Update(dto.AddressDTO); // update the value object - address
       }
   }
   ```

As you can see here, the `Person` domain references the `PersonDetailsDTO`. This feels wrong to me as DTOs are means to present the data in the domain to its clients while not exposing the domain itself. and the domain should **not** be concerned with how it's presented to the clients.

Also IMO the DTOs should live in the `My.Company.Service` project as it's the service that defines the operation/data transfer contracts.

But then how would the service pass the details on to the domain? Would it have to be a loooong list of parameters: `person.Update(firstName, lastName, age, gender, street1, street2, state, postcode...)`. This certainly looks wrong to me.

Or does the domain have to define yet another set of it's own "DTOs" to receive client data?

I have gone through a LOT of tutorials and SO posts and no one seem to share my concern, so I'm starting to think I'm missing something here, could someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: I'm pretty sure that you don't want to *update* a person (there may be an exception to the rule, but usually this sounds like *CRUD* terminology which you want to avoid in DDD). Maybe https://www.thenativeweb.io/blog/2017-10-25-09-46-ddd-and-co-part-1-whats-wrong-with-crud/ is of interest to you.

Comment: Yeah that's a good point, thanks I'll def have a look at it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do as follows.
You already have a Value Object named `Address` similarly you could have another Value Object as `PersonalDetails` which will contain firstName, lastName, age, gender etc. and the `Person` entity will have two behaviors like `updatePersonalDetails()` and `updateAddress()`. Your application service will look like below.

```
public void UpdatePerson(PersonDetailsDTO dto)
{
    var person = _personRepository.GetById(dto.PersonId);
    Address address = new Address(dto.getStreet1, dto.getStreet2,...);
    PersonalDetails details = new PersonalDetails(dto.getFirstName,dto.getLastName(),...);
    person.updatePersonalDetails(details);
    person.updateAddress(address);
   _personRepository.save(person);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this makes most sense to me. Perhaps I'll also abstract away the creation of these objects into factories.

Answer (score 2):

According to the [Dependency inversion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle) and DDD, the `Value objects` (the `DTOs` as you call them: `PersonDetailsDTO` and `Address`) should be **[owned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_inversion_principle#Implementations)** by the Domain. This means that they should reside in the Domain namespace/package/project. And BTW, those `Value objects` can be used all the way up to the Presentation layer and back.

Secondly, they are not `DTOs` (Data transfer objects) because there is no expensive remote call involved, but `Value objects` (cohesive data and possible behavior); read more [here](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/LocalDTO.html) how to not use them as an anti-pattern.

Last but not least, you should name your methods with terms from the Ubiquitous language (`person.Update` does not seem to be from the UL). I'm not saying 100% that is your case because I don't know your domain, I'm just saying that you should pay attention to these important details (naming things).

Comment: Thanks, @Constantin. Sorry it wasn't clear in my question but the service is indeed a remote WCF interface. I also don't think I should be leaking the value objects into the presentation layer as they contain business logic. But thanks for your insights!!

Comment: @JoelMin You should follow KISS. Also, using a VO in presentation layer does not mean that business logic is leaking. Leaking is something else.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement Object to Object mapping. It means that Service layer is responsible for creating and populating domain objects based on DTO by mapping values from the DTO instance received from client.

You can take advantage of [Automapper](http://automapper.org/) library to simplify object-to-object mapping.
Of course it can be served for domain to DTO if needed.